# List object inside object

Tags: javascript

I have an object like this:

```
var Data={arg1:"hi",arg2:"hey"}

var Result={"46058":Data,"50545":Data}
```

I want to list all values inside `Result` variable.How can I do this ? For example output should be like this:

```
46058's arg1 value's = hi
46058's arg2 value's = hey

50545's arg1 value's = hi
50545's arg2 value's = hey
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@doldt's answer has you on the right path. But because of your nested data example, you'll need to have multiple loops to get the expected output.

```
var data = {arg1: "hi",arg2: "hey"};
var result = {"46058": data,"50545": data};

for (var outerKey in result) {
    for (var innerKey in result[outerKey]) {
        console.log(outerKey + "'s " + innerKey + " value = " + result[outerKey][innerKey]);
    }
}
```

The output would be:

```
46058's arg1 value = hi
46058's arg2 value = hey
50545's arg1 value = hi
50545's arg2 value = hey
```

And a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/ykn6nn5L/1/). Be sure to check the console output.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, here's two.

You can use the for..in syntax, like this:

```
for (attribute in Result) {
    console.log(Result[attribute]);
}
```

You can also use Object.keys(Result) to get an array containing all the keys in Result, which you can use to look up the values in the object:

```
var keys = Object.keys(Result);
for(var i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    console.log(Result[keys[i]]);
}
```

*Note: I suggest not starting your variable names with capital letters, in Javascript conventions that usually signals a constructor function.*